# Xcode 6.4 Archiving process stuck on compiling

Tags: xcode, archive

Finally got to archiving my project to put it on iTunes connect. When I archive my project, it gets stuck on "Compiling Swift source files". A normal build takes like 30 seconds to a minute. I've been waiting over an hour for this archiving process to finish. It's still compiling my source files? Was there a step I missed in this process that could cause this?